# Conda environment to python wheel

Tags: python, download, conda, python-wheel

I am looking for a way to download a wheel from a `conda` environment. Here is what I mean and what I would like to do.
I have this `conda` environment that I download using this command:

```
 conda install -c bioconda mageck
```

I would like to have a wheel like mageck.whl in order to reinstall the `conda` environment offline in a next installation using `pip install mageck.whl` or any other extension that can let me install all the packages for future installation. The aim is to have a `dockerfile` that can be 100% reproducible at least from the library version and dependencies, installing the environment only using the package downloaded.

Comment: You are looking for [conda pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/)

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/conda-incubator/conda-press suits your specific case, but it hasn't been updated in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some potential solutions if I understand your problem correctly.

- Have you tried to create an isolated software environment?

```
conda create -c bioconda -n mageckenv mageck
```

after that, you can activate the environment:

```
source activate mageckenv
```

- Here you have the link to install using Docker

  - https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/mageck/README.html